# I can't customize slotDuration properly in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, angular, fullcalendar, ionic2

I am using angular `fullcalendar` and I want to disable slots, which means in every interval, I get only one slot, so I set:

```
("#calendar").fullcalendar({
    ...
    slotDuration: "00:90:01",
    slotLabelInterval:'00:90:00'
    ...
});
```

However, this is not displaying the calendar correctly.

[image]

If I remove `slotDuration` from `fullcalendar` options, I get this result, which is not what I want, because the slot is still there.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im a little unsure of your question but if you want only single slot in agenda View. i.e. 24hrs.you can do this. Remove slot duration and use the following:

```
("#calendar").fullcalendar({
    ...
    slotLabelInterval:'24:00:00'
    ...
});
```

let me know how it works.

Comment: That's not what I meant :/ Iwant slot Label Interval get 1h30min and the same value in slotDuration which means for each interval only one slot ! thnks anyway :)